# In my main, how to access string array in an array object? How to access parameter from constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

UML is attached. I want to create a readonly property of pre which is an array of string. When I create an object in the main and try to set name and pre it is showing me an error.

[UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP4BQ.png)

```
using System;

class Unit
{
    private string _name;
    private string[] _pre;

    public Unit(string name, string[] pre)
    {
        _name = name;
        _pre = new string[2];
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public string[] Pre { get { return _pre; } }
}

class Program
{
    public static void DisplayInfo(Unit[] _u)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_u[i].Name + _u[i].Pre);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Unit[] unitarraytest = new Unit[2];

        unitarraytest[0] = new Unit("test 1", "test 3");
        unitarraytest[1] = new Unit("test 2", "test 4");

        DisplayInfo(unitarraytest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays must be assigned a length upfront. If the length isn't known and can be dynamic you're better off using something like List.

Comment: @sr28 as per the requirements I can not use list.

Comment: What is the purpose of the parameter 'string [] pre'? This is being passed in but assigned to nothing.

Comment: And you have a constructor that take a string and an array of strings, but you try to pass a string and then another string. This will not compile.

Comment: Also the DisplayInfo is wrong. Pre is an array of strings. If you want to print its content you need a loop over the elements of Pre (inside the loop over the elements of the Unit class passed)

Comment: @Steve yeah that is where im getting connfused at, how will I pass stuff to the array string.

Comment: _unitarraytest[0] = new Unit("test 1", new [] {"test 3", "test 3 bis"});_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example makes little sense. You Unit constructor takes a parameter for "Pre", but immediately throws it away and allocates a new empty string array instead. It should probably be written like

```
class Unit
{
    public Unit(string name, string[] pre)
    {
        Name = name;
        Pre  = pre;
    }

    public string Name { get;}
    public string[] Pre { get;}
}
```

When creating Unit objects you actually need to create an array for the "Pre" parameter. Like `new Unit("Name", new []{"pre1", "pre2"});`

And when outputting the strings you need to access the individual strings in the array, or combine them to a larger string, for example like `Console.WriteLine(_u[i].Name + string.Join(" , ", _u[i].Pre));`

Comment: Thank you, it works fine but still its showing as System.string when I run it